# Kotlin - Spring REST - ControllerAdvice with ExceptionHandler won't get invoked

Tags: java, spring, rest, exception, kotlin

In order to simplify my error handling i wanted an ExceptionHandler, i have used the 4. point on http://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring .

My exception handler class looks like follows:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class APIExceptionHandler : ResponseEntityExceptionHandler() {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = [(TestException::class)])
    fun handleConflict(exception: TestException, request: WebRequest): ResponseEntity<Any> {
        println("Handle")
        return handleExceptionInternal(exception, "Response Body", HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request)
    }
}
```

`TestException` is just a simple `Exception` that extends `RuntimeException`

```
class TestException : RuntimeException()
```

Anyhow, in my `RestController` i am simply throwing an exception as soon as any call is made:

```
@GetMapping("/lobby/close")
fun closeLobby(@RequestParam(value = "uuid") uuid: String, @RequestHeader(value = "userSession") userSession: String): ResponseEntity<Any> {
    throw TestException()
}
```

But the exception handler is not invoked.

However, calling this:

```
@GetMapping("/lobby/error")
fun error(): ResponseEntity<Any> {
    throw TestException()
}
```

it is invoked.

I don't quite understand what the difference is, besides of the first version expecting parameters and a specific header.

**UPDATE 24.03.2018**

The problem seems to be, that the ExceptionHandler isn't being invoked if the clients request was malformed.

By default a malformed request leads to a pretty detailed error report, but the custom ExceptionHandler seems to disable this functionality.

Comment: When you invoke `closeLobby()`, do you see the exception in the logs?

Comment: Nope, i don't see anything.

Comment: What http response do you get? 404?

Comment: I get a 400 response. However, it is not comming from my exception, because i get a 400 even if i change it over there.

Comment: Sounds like you just aren't making the request properly. What happens if you remove the exception and return a proper value?

Comment: @Todd you are right, it only doesn't work if the request is malformed, but anyways, the exception handler shouldn't break every other case of exception handling, should it?

Answer (score 13):

I got it working, here is my code.

```
@ControllerAdvice
class ControllerAdviceRequestError : ResponseEntityExceptionHandler() {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = [(UserAlreadyExistsException::class)])
    fun handleUserAlreadyExists(ex: UserAlreadyExistsException,request: WebRequest): ResponseEntity<ErrorsDetails> {
        val errorDetails = ErrorsDetails(Date(),
                "Validation Failed",
                ex.message!!
        )
        return ResponseEntity(errorDetails, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    }
}
```

Exception class

```
class UserAlreadyExistsException(override val message: String?) : Exception(message)
```

Data class

```
data class ErrorsDetails(val time: Date, val message: String, val details: String)
```

MyController:

```
@PostMapping(value = ["/register"])
    fun register(@Valid @RequestBody user: User): User {
        if (userService.exists(user.username)) {
            throw UserAlreadyExistsException("User with username ${user.username} already exists")
        }
        return userService.create(user)
    }
```

Comment: I tried this, it works ONLY if I have to handle the specific exceptions. It fails as soon as I have 2 methods, one for user-defined exceptions and one for general exceptions. Whenever a user-defined exception was thrown it was caught by the method annotated with `@ExceptionHandler(Exception::class)` and not with `@ExceptionHandler(UserAlreadyExistsException::class)`. Any solutions? When I tried it in java it worked like a charm but not in kotlin.

Comment: I do not know if there is any specific bug related to kotin in this case try broadening your search

Answer (score 0):

For now i have a solution, even though this shouldn't be the desired way i think.

Since my controllers had no base class anyways, i have no created a `BaseController` that contains functions that handle the Exceptions, those functions are simply annotated with `ExceptionHandler` and their method list contains the `Exception` they should handle.

Since the `BasicController` class doesn't extend any other Spring class that handles exceptions, it doesn't override the default behaviour for handling problems like malformed requests.

I gladly accept any better solution, because i don't think this should be the desired way.

Answer (score 0):

Please read here: https://newbedev.com/setting-precedence-of-multiple-controlleradvice-exceptionhandlers

regarding:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
```

and

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
```

You can combine these to handle more specific exceptions first